# How to show temp files in android

Tags: android, temporary-files

Hi i am able to create temp files.
i am trying to display temp file byy using the following logic .

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(mFile), contentType);
```

Here mFile is the Temp file(ex:temp.html-1148819481.tmp).
But it is telling "web page not available".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are trying to display Html file from other application (Ex:HTMLviewr ),that application is not accepting the temp files.so i put the files in application Files directory.and the i am giving that path.then it is working fine.and one more thing is the file name should not contain spaces.so i am removing the spaces and the storing in files directory ...

Answer (score 0):

Other processes do not have the right to view your files on internal storage, by default. Either:

- Create the file to be `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`, or
- Use a `WebView` to display it in your own activity (since it appears that your file is in HTML), or
- Create a `ContentProvider` to serve the file, and use the appropriate `content://` `Uri` in your `Intent`